# [ROS2] generating DDS .idl files from .msg ROS Message Format

Tags: ros, ros2, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to create .idl descriptions from the ros message description format.

There is the `rosidl_generate_dds_interfaces` package and cmake macro.

How would I use this for instance for the std_msgs or trajectory_msgs package?
I'm currently trying

```
rosidl_generate_dds_interfaces(std_msgs_idl IDL_FILES ${msg_files}OUTPUT_SUBFOLDERS "idl")
```

In `std_msgs/CMakeLists.txt`

Thanks
Jochen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268396/%5Bros2%5D-generating-dds-.idl-files-from-.msg-ros-message-format/) by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-09**:
Are you trying to do this to use the IDL outside ROS2, or are you trying to generate msgs for your ROS2 package?

**Comment by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on 2017-08-09**:
yes, i'm trying to use that idl with plain rti dds on a non ros machine

**Comment by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on 2017-08-09**:
i feel like i'm just missing a small step or so. there is a rosidl_generator_dds_idl__arguments.json file generated in the build folder.. seems like the python script is not called correctly or so

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-08-09**:
Are you getting an error message?

Also, you should be able to get the idl files out from a normal ROS 2 build. They will have been installed I believe.

**Comment by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on 2017-08-09**:
i do get an error message from the install target which is looking for  /ros2_ws/build/std_msgs/rosidl_generator_dds_idl/std_msgs/msg/idl/Bool_.idl" and does not find the file.
I do not see the .idl files installed somewhere. that would be the easiest thing of course :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the `.idl` files that we generate for a `.msg` file if you build from source and copy them out of the installation folder. However, you need to build with an rmw implementation that actually uses the `.idl` files for them to be generated. The reason you don't see them, probably, is that you're using our default rmw implementation of Fast-RTPS which does not generate or consume `.idl` files currently.

However, if you build, for example, with Connext it will generate and install the files to the install folder, in the case of `std_msgs` it would be in `path/to/install/share/std_msgs/msg/dds_connext`. The reason you have to use Connext (or an rmw implementation like it) is that the generated `.idl` files are specific to the underlying vendor. Despite being a standard there are small variations in the use of the `.idl` files between vendors. For example, the way in which you specify a "key field" in the `.idl` file differs between vendors, I believe it is different for Connext and OpenSplice at least.

So the easiest way would be to use Connext or OpenSplice and build from source. Then the `.idl` files will be generated for you and installed. No matter which you use the `.idl` file produced would be a good starting place as the differences between them are small.

You should also be able to use the generator directly to generate generic `.idl` files from our `.msg` files (all the code and tools are there), but you might have a hard time right now since we don't do that ourselves. If you find a change that would make that easier then let us know, we'd be happy to make that use case better even though we don't need it ourselves.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on 2017-08-10**:
works like a charm, thanks a lot !
since i want to use rti dds anyways on the other machine it's the best solution

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-06-04**:
@william @jochen.mueck How can i access the published and subscribed data by accessing the idl files ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-06-04**:
@aakash_sehgal please don't ask questions in comments. This is a solved question from close to a year ago people won't be reviewing this question.. Also you already asked this question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/293158/how-can-i-use-the-ros2-idl-files-to-connect-with-a-non-ros-machine/

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-06-05**:
@tfoote : noted for future and deleted the redundant question